# Mysql Query to Elasticsearch Query conversion

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

How to convert the below Mysql query to Elasticsearch query?

```
SELECT  
distinct t.id as 'Task ID',
cust.name as 'Customer' ,
ticketType.type as 'Task Type',
t.created_time as 'Created Date',
ci.name as 'Asset'
FROM ticket t
JOIN reported_master AS rs ON reported_issue_type.id = t.reported_issuetype_id
JOIN ci_master AS ci ON ci.id = t.primary_ci 
JOIN ticket_source_master  AS source_master ON source_master.id = t.ticket_source_id          
and source_master.name='Bus'
where t.engagement_id=14653  and t.created_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
```

I am new to ES and don't know how to write a query for join condition.

Comment: `reported_master AS rs ON reported_issue_type.id = t.reported_issuetype_id` this doesn't make sense, so I don't see how we can help with that

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "JOIN" in elastic so you need restructure your data...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments section, you can't do JOINs in elasticsearch like/as convenient as in SQL/a relational database.

However, you may want to take a look at the [SQL Translate API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html) which translates SQL-Statements into native Elasticsearch queries.

Furthermore I suggest to take a look at the [Join datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) and [Joining Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) to understand the mechanism/requirements for joining documents in Elasticsearch. **But I strongly recommend changing your data structure instead of joining documents.**

Hope this helps.